# Jquery: loop through code and extract value into associated class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop through my code detecting every instance of an input with an ID of **#hiddenFile** and outputting it's shortened filename into an associated span with a class of **.results**

How do I do it so that the right file names are output into corresponding spans associated near the hidden fields? there could be any number of files ultimately - but my example give three:

**This is my the JS**

```
$( "input#hiddenFile" ).each(function( index ) {

  var fileName, fileExtension;
  fileName = $('input#hiddenFile').val();
  fileExtension = fileName.substr((fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

  $('.results').html(index + fileExtension);

});
```

**This is my HTML**

```
<!-- File One -->
<input type="hidden" name="options[designFile]" id="hiddenFile" value="{{ item.options['designFile'] }}">
<span class="results"></span>

<!-- File Two -->
<input type="hidden" name="options[designFile]" id="hiddenFile" value="{{ item.options['designFile'] }}">
<span class="results"></span>

<!-- File Three -->
<input type="hidden" name="options[designFile]" id="hiddenFile" value="{{ item.options['designFile'] }}">
<span class="results"></span>
```

Comment: This is invalid. You should have unique ids. Each element should have a unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An ID is a uniqe name in HTML.** There should only be one ID named "hiddenFile" per document! Don't do that! But if you use another selector, like changing `id` to a `class`, this is what you are looking for:

```
<!-- File One -->
<input type="hidden" name="options[designFile]" class="hiddenFile" value="{{ item.options['designFile'] }}">
<span class="results"></span>

<!-- File Two -->
<input type="hidden" name="options[designFile]" class="hiddenFile" value="{{ item.options['designFile'] }}">
<span class="results"></span>

<!-- File Three -->
<input type="hidden" name="options[designFile]" class="hiddenFile" value="{{     item.options['designFile'] }}">
<span class="results"></span>
```

---

```
$("input.hiddenFile").each(function(index) {
    var fileName = $(this).val();
        fileExtension = fileName.substr((fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

    $(this).next().html(index + fileExtension);
});
```